# No shipping method has been selected

Tags: customization, woocommerce-offtopic

I've had a look on Google, tried a few things, but can't find a solution for this.

I'm trying to set up Woocommerce so that I have one item which has free delivery, however when I get to the cart/checkout I get this error:

> No shipping method has been selected. Please double check your
>   address, or contact us if you need any help.

This prevents me from going off to Paypal and completing the order. I need only this one item to be free shipping, and it needs to be able to be part of an order with other products which do have a shipping cost.

Is anyone able to point me into the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: Hi. WooCommerce questions are off-topic here by their own. However you can discuss your problem in [WooCommerce](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61002/woocommerce) chat room.